# How to change indices on an integral: from (1/x) to 1, to 1 to x

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

On this year's ([2020](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2020.pdf)) Putnam exam, [solution](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2020s.pdf) to problem B3 contains the following line:

$$h(x) = 1+\int^1_{1/x} h(cx)dc = 1+\frac1 x\int^x_1h(c)dc$$

Taking the former equality as given, I would not know how to make this move. If true, I'd suppose this implies some general proposition (for at least some set of functions),

$$A = \int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} h(x)dc \implies A= a^{-1}(x) \int _{g(x)a(x)} ^{f(x)a(x)}h(x*a^{-1}(x))dc $$

Which may be easily shown false with an arbitrary example.

So, what's the mathematical tool used in the first change of integration parameters?

Comment: This is just substitution.  Let $u =xc$ so that $du = x dc$.

Comment: post as an answer and Ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $c$ is our variable we may substitute with $u = xc$.  This gives $du = x \ dc$ and so $\frac{1}{x} \ du = dc$.  Our original bounds of $c=1/x$ and $c=1$ convert to $u = 1$ and $u=x$ respectively.  This gives
$$
\int_{1/x}^1 h(cx) \ dc =  \frac{1}{x} \int_{1}^{x} h(u) \ du.
$$
The interior variable is dummy, so the last integral may be written as $\frac{1}{x} \int_{1}^{x} h(c) \ dc$, which is what you wanted.